# Element heights exceed grid layout limits with use codemirror and xterm.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, codemirror, xtermjs

I'm trying to put CodeMirror and Xterm.js in a GridLayout like the following code. I'm specifying `1fr 200px 80px` for `grid-template-rows` here and I'm having problems with this.

**Occurred problems**

1. If the CodeMirror text area contains enough text, the height will increase with the amount of text. I'm hoping for the behavior of displaying scrollbars without sticking out of `1fr`.
2. xterm.js sticks out of the container. xterm.js sticks out of the container. I expect xterm.js to fit in the size specified by `grid-template-rows`.

How can I solve these problems? Thank you.

```js
const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/x-csrc",
  viewportMargin: Infinity
});
const codemirror = document.getElementById("code-mirror");
editor.setSize("100%", "100%");

const term = new Terminal();
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
term.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ')

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  editor.setSize();
}, false);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.editor {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px 80px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/3.14.5/xterm.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/3.14.5/xterm.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editor">
    <div id="code-mirror">
      <textarea id="editor">
typedef struct {
  void* arg_socket;
  zmq_msg_t* arg_msg;
  char* arg_string;
  unsigned long arg_len;
  int arg_int, arg_command;

  int signal_fd;
  int pad;
  void* context;
  sem_t sem;
} acl_zmq_context;
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="terminal">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button type="button">
        run
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```